# Expand string patterns in Elisp

Tags: strings, combinatorics, elisp

I need to expand logical patterns to list of strings.

For example I have the following definition:

```
(expand-pattern '(and "xy"
                      (or "1" "2")
                      (or (and "ab0"
                               (or "1" "2" "3"))
                          "cd01")))
```

Which evaluates to the following list of strings:

```
("xy1ab01" "xy2ab01" "xy1ab02" "xy2ab02" "xy1ab03" "xy2ab03" "xy1cd01" "xy2cd01")
```

I wrote the following code:

```
(defun expand-pattern (pattern)
  (defun expat (parents expr)
    (pcase expr
      ((or (pred stringp)
           (pred numberp))   (mapcar (lambda (parent)
                                     (cons expr parent))
                                     parents))
      (`(and ,first)         (expat parents first))
      (`(and ,first . ,rest) (expat (expat parents first)
                                    (cons 'and rest)))
      (`(or . ,args)         (apply #'append 
                                    (mapcar (lambda (arg)
                                              (expat parents arg))
                                            args)))
      (_                     (error "unknown %S" expr))))
  (mapcar (lambda (tokens)
            (mapconcat (lambda (token)
                         (format "%s" token))
                       (reverse tokens)
                       ""))
          (expat '(()) pattern)))
```

I am new to Emacs Lisp and would like to know, if this is a reasonable way to solve the problem in Elisp or if it can be optimized, to simplify the code.

Answer (score 6):

### Scoping

In Emacs Lisp a nesting a `defun` inside another `defun` does not create a lexically scoped function. The symbol for the 'nested' function is still interned at in the current `objarray`. The behavior is unlike that of Scheme.

In Emacs Lisp `let ((f (lambda (x) (body))))...(funcall f some-value)` is the general structure for a 'local' function.

### Formatting

The formatting of the code within the call to `pcase` is difficult to read. When the condition and consequent cannot be listed on the same line, it is probably more common to place the consequent below the conditional.

### Suggested Alternative Format

```
(defun expand-pattern (pattern)
  (mapcar (lambda (tokens)
            (mapconcat (lambda (token)
                         (format "%s" token))
                       (reverse tokens)
                       ""))
          (expat '(()) pattern)))

(defun expat (parents expr)
  "Utility function for expand pattern."
  (pcase expr
    ((or (pred stringp)
         (pred numberp))
     (mapcar (lambda (parent)
               (cons expr parent))
             parents))
    (`(and ,first)
     (expat parents first))
    (`(and ,first . ,rest)
     (expat (expat parents first)
            (cons 'and rest)))
    (`(or . ,args)
     (apply #'append 
            (mapcar (lambda (arg)
                      (expat parents arg))
                    args)))
    (_ (error "unknown %S" expr))))
```

### Other Remarks

Because `expat` throws an error, it might make sense to have `expand-pattern` invoke `expat` within a `try...catch` block. Alternatively, `expat` could return `nil` when no match is found. If `nil` is a possible return value from processing the pattern, then a "Lispy" thing to do is to return two values, the first being the result of processing the expression and the second being either `nil` or `t` to indicate an error or no error.

Comment: `expat` is an internal helper function, I did not want to export. So `letrec` is the only way to define something within the lexical scope?

Comment: @ceving You can also use `cl-labels`and `cl-flet`, depending on if you have a need to call functions bound in the same form or not (anything defined in `cl-flet` is "non-shadowing", whereas `cl-labels` "shadows" function definitions).

Comment: @ceving I've edited my answer to show the `let...funcall` syntax for creating 'local' functions in Emacs Lisp. The Emacs Lisp Manual is a bit short in this regard unfortunately. I've sent a documentation suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

It's unusual to `defun` within a function.  If you just want `expat` available while executing `expand-pattern`, you should use use `letrec`:

```
(defun expand-pattern (pattern)
  (letrec ((expat (lambda (parents expr)
                    (pcase expr
                      ((or (pred stringp)
                           (pred numberp))   (mapcar (lambda (parent)
                                                       (cons expr parent))
                           parents))
                      (`(and ,first)         (funcall expat parents first))
                      (`(and ,first . ,rest) (funcall expat (funcall expat parents first)
                                                      (cons 'and rest)))
                      (`(or . ,args)         (apply #'append 
                                                    (mapcar (lambda (arg)
                                                              (funcall expat parents arg))
                                                            args)))
                      (_                     (error "unknown %S" expr))))))
    (mapcar (lambda (tokens)
              (mapconcat (lambda (token)
                           (format "%s" token))
                         (reverse tokens)
                         ""))
            (funcall expat '(()) pattern))))
```

This way, the binding of `expat` doesn't live beyond the function.

It looks like what you're doing is a 'reduce' type of operation - you may find it worthwhile to look into `cl-reduce` and related functions.

Comment: But the `funcall`s do not make it more readable.

Comment: Emacs Lisp does not have `letrec` or an equivalent. In Common Lisp the equivalent is `labels`. `(require 'cl)` will provide access to `labels` in Emacs Lisp, however a function defined with `labels` in Emacs Lisp still requires `funcall` for invocation. I believe this is because symbols in a `let` type structure are not interned, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: @ben: *`letrec` is a Lisp macro in '`subr.el'`*.  Can you explain how it is different to `letrec` in other Lisp implementations? The only languages I know from this family are Emacs Lisp and standard Scheme, so perhaps I've missed some subtlety.  Certainly the code I wrote in this answer produces the expected results for the example in the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the availability of `letrec. The source code comments say it is only useful in lexical-binding mode. It does not show up in the Emacs Lisp Manual. I'd say the big difference with Scheme is that a function defined with `letrec` in Emacs Lisp requires invocation via `funcall` whereas Scheme does not. Common Lisp provides `labels` to allow invocation without `funcall`.